# Is there research evidence to suggest that waking up slowly is more beneficial than waking up abruptly?

Tags: sleep

There are several articles I've found which seem to anecdotally back up the suggestion that waking up slowly is better than waking up abruptly, in terms of combatting sleep inertia:

https://www.nbcnews.com/better/pop-culture/make-your-day-better-stay-bed-longer-really-ncna837176

https://qz.com/1301170/sleep-inertia-explains-why-you-feel-so-groggy-when-you-wake-up/

https://www.brightontheday.com/4-benefits-of-waking-up-slowly-and-how-to-actually-do-it/

However, I want to know if there have been any studies conducted which directly compared the effects on sleep inertia of waking up slowly and mindfully vs. swiftly and energetically. I wasn't able to find any through Google Scholar.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question was better suited for here or for Psychology and Neuroscience, as there seems to be some overlap with regards to sleep. If users feel it would be better posted on the other site, let me know.

Comment: Sleep inertia isn't really a medical issue, so I think this will fit better in P&N.